Building GCC Fails with "make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found."
I followed the GCC Installation instructions [1] to download the source and configure my build, but when I try to make from the toplevel dir (with MAINTAINERS and Makefile.in) I always get the same error: make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. I don't know how to proceed with the Build step of the installation guide.
Edit: I've noticed that my objdir/config.log file ends with configure: exit 1 and I'm unsure if it is expected or if it indicates that the configuration failed and the project is not in a viable state for building.
I have tried

make

make install

make bootstrap

make -f Makefile.in
This fails with the message Makefile:26: *** missing separator.  Stop. because of lines starting with @if and @endif. This autogenerated file has a lot of these lines, I doubt I'm supposed to manually remove them.


My full workflow up to this point:
# Get the source
~$ mkdir gcc; cd gcc
~/gcc$ git clone git://gcc.gnu.org/git/gcc.git .

# Make objdir/ and configure my desired build
~$ mkdir ARM; cd ARM
~/gcc/ARM$ ../configure --prefix=$HOME --target=aarch64-none-elf

# Try to "just make"
~/gcc/ARM$ cd ..
~/gcc$ make # :(

Some maybe relevant details
~/gcc$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 11.4.1 20231218 (Red Hat 11.4.1-3)
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
~/gcc$ make --version
GNU Make 4.3
Built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
~/gcc$ git show
commit 3e89a4d5138e585713604135d4c2601244055e82 (HEAD -> master, origin/trunk, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Author: Jason Merrill <jason@redhat.com>
Date:   Sat Nov 16 15:25:04 2024 -0500
...
~/gcc$ ls
ABOUT-NLS           config.sub       fixincludes   libcody       libitm           ltmain.sh           missing
ar-lib              configure        gcc           libcpp        libobjc          lt~obsolete.m4      mkdep
ARM                 configure.ac     gnattools     libdecnumber  libphobos        lto-plugin          mkinstalldirs
ChangeLog           contrib          gotools       libffi        libquadmath      ltoptions.m4        move-if-change
ChangeLog.jit       COPYING          include       libgcc        libsanitizer     ltsugar.m4          multilib.am
ChangeLog.tree-ssa  COPYING3         INSTALL       libgfortran   libssp           ltversion.m4        README
compile             COPYING3.LIB     install-sh    libgm2        libstdc++-v3     MAINTAINERS         SECURITY.txt
config              COPYING.LIB      libada        libgo         libtool-ldflags  maintainer-scripts  symlink-tree
config.guess        COPYING.RUNTIME  libatomic     libgomp       libtool.m4       Makefile.def        test-driver
config-ml.in        c++tools         libbacktrace  libgrust      libvtv           Makefile.in         ylwrap
config.rpath        depcomp          libcc1        libiberty     ltgcc.m4         Makefile.tpl        zlib


https://gcc.gnu.org/install/index.html

EDIT: fixed some details and added some details

Check No targets specified and no makefile found

The problem lies in config.log - the logfile created when running configure. The telltale sign is the last line indicates an error running the script - a non-zero exit number - 'configure: exit 1' in my case. Scrolling up from there shows that configure could not locate some of gcc's dependencies (mpc, mpfr, gmp). I just need to install them first, then once configure finishes successfully I'll probably find a ready Makefile in the srcdir.
